# How to perform ASK queries?

Tags: java, sparql, sesame

If I want to do a SPARQL SELECT query in in Sesame repository through Netbeans, I use the following code (and I get three values in the binding set). How can I do an ASK query which return just one boolean?

```
TupleQuery tupleQuery = con.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, queryString);
TupleQueryResult result = tupleQuery.evaluate();
List<String> bindingNames = result.getBindingNames();

try {
    while (result.hasNext()) {    
        BindingSet bindingSet = result.next();
        Value firstValue1 = bindingSet.getValue(bindingNames.get(0));
        Value firstValue2 = bindingSet.getValue(bindingNames.get(1));
        Value firstValue3 = bindingSet.getValue(bindingNames.get(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: also asked and answered at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/24793/how-to-perfom-sparql-ask-query-in-sesame-repository-through-netbeans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your `con` is a `RepositoryConnection`, you'd use some version of [`prepareBooleanQuery(…)`](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/repository/RepositoryConnection.html#prepareBooleanQuery%28org.openrdf.query.QueryLanguage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).  That will return a [`BooleanQuery`](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/query/BooleanQuery.html) whose [`evaluate()`](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/query/BooleanQuery.html#evaluate%28%29) method returns a boolean.  Modying the code you presented would leave you with

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = con.prepareBoleanQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, queryString);
boolean result = booleanQuery.evaluate();
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. Here is the code:

 BooleanQuery bq = con.prepareBooleanQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, queryString);
        try {
     boolean b = bq.evaluate();
     System.out.println(b);
 } finally {

 }

Comment: @vijendra If you're not `catch`ing anything, and you're not doing anything in the `finally` block, why use a `try { … } finally { … }` at all?